# Power system question: How do you derive the reactive power transfer equation?

Tags: power-supply, math, formula-derivation

I'm reading the EPRI Power System Dynamics Tutorial textbook.

On page 3-12, it defines the reactive power as

$$
Q_{S}=\frac{V_{S}^2}{Z}(V_{S}X_{L}-X_{L}V_{R}\cos\delta+RV_{R}\sin\delta-\frac{V_{S}}{X_{C}}Z^2)
$$

The S subscript stands for sending side, R subscript stands for receiving side, \$\delta\$ is the phase difference between sending and receiving side voltages, \$Z\$ is the impedance of the line defined as \$R+jX_{L}\$. The equation above is simplified by assuming that the series resistance (R) is much smaller than the series reactance (\$X_{L}\$).
$$
Q_{S}=\frac{V_{S}^2-V_{S}V_{R}\cos\delta}{X_{L}}-\frac{V_{R}^2}{X_{C}}
$$

Because of the \$Z^2\$ in the denominator, I get \${(jX_L)}^2\$ in the denominator, which becomes \$-X_{L}^2\$, and as such, my final equation for \$Q_{S}\$ has a negative in front of it. I would like to know how to derive the equation for \$Q_{S}\$, reactive power transfer.

---

Here is a little bit more context:

Power transfer from sending side is \$S_{S}\$.

$$
S_{S} = V_{S} I_{S}
$$

$$I_{S}=\frac{V_{S}-V_{R}}{Z}+\frac{V_{S}}{X_{C}}$$

$$Z=R+jX_{L}$$

Then

$$S_{S} = P_{S}+j Q_{S}= V_{S} (\frac{V_{S}-V_{R}}{Z}+\frac{V_{S}}{X_{C}})$$

The above equation is expanded, and the terms with a j in front of it is grouped in the reactive power transfer \$Q_{S}\$ and the terms without a j in front of it is grouped into the active power transfer \$P_S\$.

Answer (score 3):

Your \$S_S\$ equation needs a conjugate on the current.

$$S_S=V_S{I_S}^*$$

So, the circuit they use in the EPRI document you reference is as below,

[image]

For the power transfer part, as you have apparently already determined, you can ignore the shunt capacitors.  You only need to include them as additional var from their respective bus (\$V^2/X_C\$).

So, letting \$\overline{I}\$ be the current through the line impedance and letting \$\overline{V_R}=V_R\angle0°\$, \$\overline{V_S}=V_S\angle\theta°=V_Se^{j\theta}\$, and \$\overline{Z}=R+jX_L=Ze^{j\phi}\$ we have,

$$\overline{I}=\frac{V_Se^{j\theta}-V_R}{R+jX_L}$$
$$\phi=tan^{-1}\frac{X_L}{R}$$

Now, from \$\overline{S}=\overline{V_S}\text{ }\overline{I}^*\$ we find the apparent power sent down the line from sending end as,

$$\overline{S_S}=V_Se^{j\theta}\text{ }\overline{I}^*=V_Se^{j\theta} \left(\frac{V_Se^{-j\theta}-V_R}{Ze^{-j\phi}}\right) = \frac{V_S^2e^{j\theta}-V_SV_Re^{j(\theta+\phi)}}{Z}   $$

Using [Eulers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), \$e^{j\theta}=\cos\theta+j\sin\theta \$ that boils down to this,

$$\overline{S_S}=\frac{V_S^2}{Z}\left(\cos\phi+j\sin\phi\right)-\frac{V_SV_R}{Z}\left[\cos(\theta+\phi)+j\sin\left(\theta+\phi\right)\right]   $$

Then you just collect the \$j\$ terms to find the \$Q\$ component and the real terms for \$P\$.

If you go further and let \$R=0\$ you get the following familiar equations,

$$P=\operatorname{Re}{\{\overline{S}_S\}=\frac{V_SV_R\sin\theta}{X_L}}$$

$$Q=\operatorname{Im}{\{\overline{S}_S\}=\frac{V_S^2-V_SV_R\cos\theta}{X_L}}$$

Comment: I am trying to follow through with your answer to your answer to the other question, but I am unable to follow through. 

So, after substituting Euler's formula., I get the following:

S = E (cos (theta) + j sin (theta) ) x [E (cos (theta) + j sin (theta) )  - V] / (j X)

I am not sure how the trigonometry will cancel into the active power and reactive power transfer questions that we know.

Comment: Hi @Norman  I edited my answer, see if it gets you back on track.

Comment: Thank you so much for expanding on your first answer. Your first answer should have been enough by mentioning that I (current) should be the conjugate of I, but I did not know how to apply this until now. Thank you.